# how to use mxnet in python

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, mxnet

I trained a cnn in mathematica using the network lenet und exported it as MXnet. How can I use the exported JSON and PARAMS in python to predict? How to load the model? I could not find useful examples or documentation for this. I am using python 3.6 with anaconda.

Comment: Found a similar thread in mathematicastackexchange. Link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133857/how-to-export-an-mxnet?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`mxnet.model.load_checkpoint`](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/model.html?highlight=load_checkpoint#mxnet.model.load_checkpoint) function to load these files into an MXNet symbol, and parameter objects. And then you can use the Module API to bind input data to your symbol for predictions.

See [this tutorial](http://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/tutorials/basic/module.html#save-and-load) for an example of how it's done.